# How do I print an Object of MyList?

Tags: java, tostring

Any time I try to print a MyList object I get 'User@' some hex number. 
Can someone help me out with a printing function or a way to print in the main? I heard of trying to Override the toString function, but I couldn't seem to get that to work and am not sure if thats the correct thing to do.

```
public class MyList {
  private ListElement head, tail; //Forward declaration
  void add(Object value) {
    if (tail != null) {
      tail.next = new ListElement(value);
      tail = tail.next;
    }
    else {
      head = tail = new ListElement(value);
    }
  }
  Object remove() 
  {
    assert head != null; // don't remove on empty list
    Object result = head.value;
    head = head.next;
    if (head == null) { //was that the last?
      tail = null;
    }
    return result;
  }
  //Nested class needed only in the implementation of MyList
  private class ListElement {
    ListElement(Object value) {this.value = value;}
    Object value;
    ListElement next; //defaults to null as desired
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    myList anInstance = new myList();
    String someValue = "A list element";
    anInstance.add(someValue);

    String anotherValue = "Another value";
    anInstance.add(anotherValue);
  }
}
```

The override I tried went something like this:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
      return String.format(this.head);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to implement `toString()`. Do you know how string concatenation works?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to print the list?  you could either implement toString() or just print out the properties of the User you want i.e. user.firstname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is an untested implementation of the toString method. Try it out.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String myString = "";
    ListElement currentElement = head;
    while (currentElement.next != null)
    {
        if (myString.length > 0)
        {
            myString += ",";
        }
        myString += currentElement.value.toString();
        currentElement = currentElement.next;
    }
    return myString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> The override I tried went something like this:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
      return String.format(this.head);
  }
}
```

> ---

That's a start, now instead of just printing the head, use a while loop to iterate through the entire list, and create a new String that contains the information from all the elements. Then return that String.

i.e.,

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
      ListElement tail = this.tail;
      // or you might need to start at the head element depending on which way 
      // you will iterate.

      String returnString = "";

      // use a while loop here to go through your list
      // and add pertinent info from each element to the returnString

      return returnString;
  }
}
```

Note that if you were wanting to be super-efficient, you'd use a StringBuilder to do your concatenation, however for your application, this is likely over-kill and not necessary.

Note 2: Hopefully ListElement has a `toString()` method, and if so, use it inside of your while loop to get each element's info.

---

Next iteration:

```
@Override
  public String toString() {

      String returnString = "";

      ListElement currentElement = this.tail;

      while  (currentElement != null) {
         returnString += // *** get toString() info from currentElement
         currentElement = // **** reset currentElement to next element
      }

      return returnString;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think thats the problem. I don't think I could iterate through this list or at least I am not sure how to iterate through this list. I can go through array's just fine but I don't think that will work here. Do I need to make an iterator method in the class?

Comment: @RichieMiz: You know how to get the `next` element, right? You keep going til you run out of elements, til `next == null`. Also, see note about ListElement's `toString()` method. Make sure that you give this class this method and that your MyList's `toString()` method calls each ListElement's `toString()` within the while loop to get the important information.

Comment: Does this get the job done: `@Override
    public String toString() {
      ListElement = this.tail;

      String returnString = "";

      while(this.tail.next != null){
        returnString = returnString + ListElement;
        ListElement = this.tail.next;
      }

      return returnString;
  }`

Comment: @RichieMiz: 1) only post code as an edit to your question because it is quite unreadable in comments. 2) Only ask `"does this get the job done?"` **after** you've tested your code first. If it works, then you know the answer. If it doesn't compile, then don't post it. 3) Please see edit to answer.

Comment: My bad, I'm new a this. I don't really understand what you mean with adding the `toString()` method to ListElement. And I guess that leads to me not understanding the "*** get toString() info from currentElement" part of your code. Everything else makes sense to me. And I'd get the next element by setting `currentElement` equal to `this.tail.next`?

Comment: @RichieMiz: if ListElement doesn't have a toString method, then work on trying to give it one. It should return a String that displays the info held by its fields. If you use Eclipse, it will even give you a default toString method to start with and then modify.

Answer (score 1):

The default `toString()` method prints the memory address of the object (that Hex number you're seeing).

If you want something different, you need to:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    //do stuff to build a string that describes your object
    //return that string you just built
}
```

Comment: I know this part, but the inside stuff is what I'm having trouble with . Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Depends.  How exactly do you want your object described?  What is the literal string you want to print out for a given set of data within your object?

Comment: I guess I'd just wanna see this (assuming the list from the code): ["A list element", "Another value"]